# sql select query displays the column headers instead of the data in the columns

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT Week, Date, Male, Female, Children, Total, No_Of_Meetings, Total_Attendance, Visitors, New_Cells_Created, Cells_Closed, No_Of_Leaders, Members_Who_Have_Joined_Cell, Decisions_Made_For_Christ, Pers_Established_In_Local_church, Bible_Study_Groups, Bible_Study_Leaders, Endorsed_By, Designation, contact FROM `Week_Report` WHERE Cellname = 'John'
```

using

```
SELECT * FROM `Week_Report` WHERE Cellname = 'Bibiani'
```

references the cellname column header

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to improve your question. Try to expose clearly your issue.

Comment: what is a "cellname column header" exactly?

Comment: the "cellname" is the name of the column

Comment: assuming you have cellname in your table Weekly_Report you can simply use - select * from Weekly_Report WHERE CellName = 'Bibiani' if this return just headers then you are not finding any result for this record.

Comment: but the funny thing is i'v got about 3 records in the table

Comment: thanks guys, there were whitespaces before and after the records

Answer (score 0):

There were whitespaces before and at the end of the record so the sql was not finding 'Bibiani' because the actual record was like so ' Bibiani '